# WebRTC. How to disable sound during call on Android?

Tags: android, audio, webrtc

I want to have possibility to enable/disable sound during call in Android client, which uses WebRTC.

I tried to do it:

```
    LinkedList<org.webrtc.AudioTrack> tracks = audioStream.audioTracks;

    for (int i=0; i<tracks.size(); i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "track: " + i);
        tracks.get(i).setEnabled(false);
    }
```

But this case doesn't work.
May be someone know how to do it?

Seems that this method doesn't work for native app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example, of enabling, disabling audio tracks based on PeerConnection.

```
private void createHold(boolean action, int connectionId) {*/
        for (RtpReceiver rtpReceiver : peerConnections[connectionId].getReceivers()) {
            rtpReceiver.track().setEnabled(action);
        }
        for (RtpSender rtpSender : peerConnections[connectionId].getSenders()) {
            rtpSender.track().setEnabled(action);
        }
    }
```